Convergence in distribution implies $P(|X_n| \leq 1) \to P(|X| \leq 1)$?
Let $X, X_1, X_2,X_3,\ldots$ be real-valued random variables on a common probability space. Suppose that $X_n \to X$ in distribution as $X \to \infty$. Is it true that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} P(|X_n| \leq 1) = P(|X| \leq 1)$? 
My attempt. Let $F$ and $F_{X_n}$ be the CDFs of $X$ and $X_n$, respectively. I know that convergence in distribution implies $F_{X_n}(x) \to F(x)$ at every point $x$ at which $F$ is continuous. From this, I was able to prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} P(|X_n| \leq 1) = P(|X| \leq 1)$ if $F$ is continuous at 1. But what if $F$ is not continuous at 1?
I'm trying to come up with a counterexample where $F$ has a jump discontinuity at 1 and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} P(|X_n| \leq 1) \neq P(|X| \leq 1)$, but so far I haven't had any luck.

Example: $X_n$ is uniformly distributed on $[1-1/n,1+1/n]$, and $P(X=1)=1$. Then $X_n\to X$ in distribution, $P(|X|\le 1) =1$ but $P(|X_n|\le 1 )=1/2$ for each $n$.

Continuity of $F_{X}$ at both $1$ and $-1$ is required. In more generality, $X_{n}\xrightarrow{d}X\iff P(X_{n}\in K)\to P(X\in K)$ for all sets $K$ such that $P(X\in\partial(K))=0$
($\partial(K)$ denotes the boundary of $K$).
So if you take $X_{n}=-1-\frac{1}{n}$, then $X_{n}\xrightarrow{d} -1$ but $P(|X_{n}|\leq 1)=0$ and $P(|X|\leq 1)=1$.
(Note $X_{n}$ converges to $-1$ pointwise. $X_{n}$ is not even random, it is a deterministic real sequence)
